# Datatype labelling not working in form recognizer table

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using FOTT to label data inside a table. The number type data outside the table are getting recognized as number but this is not happening for the fields inside the table.
For example this is the table configuration :
[image]

And this is the result from the recognize API for the fields having number type :

```
 "Item-table/0/UnitPrice": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "valueString": "350.00",
                        "text": "350.00",
                        "page": 1,
                        "boundingBox": [
                            4.91,
                            4.8,
                            5.18,
                            4.8,
                            5.18,
                            4.88,
                            4.91,
                            4.88
                        ],
                        "confidence": 0.961
                    },
"Item-table/0/Discount": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "valueString": "0.00",
                        "text": "0.00",
                        "page": 1,
                        "boundingBox": [
                            5.99,
                            4.785,
                            6.16,
                            4.785,
                            6.16,
                            4.865,
                            5.99,
                            4.865
                        ],
                        "confidence": 0.99
                    }
```

I am using 2.1-preview.1 .Is this a bug or I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to [extract fields from tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/supervised-table-tags) was not available until 2.1-preview.3.  Can you please try using the 2.1 GA release?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.